# Error message display using js in backend

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, validation

I want to display an error message on the form/listing in magento 2 back-end. I know how to show those message using a controller.

[image]

But how can i achieve same with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Magento UI alert js for showing javascripts errors like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">{
                    require(['Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert'], function (malert) {

                        function showErrorAlert() {
                            malert({
                                title: 'Error',
                                content: 'Some error occured. Please try again later.',
                                clickableOverlay: false,
                                actions: {
                                    always: function () {}
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }</script>
```